# In Python, how do I construct an exception from another exception without raising it?

Tags: python, exception

Consider this snippet:

```
all_errors = []
for i in something:
    try:
        do_something_that_throws(i)
    except Exception as e
        # what I know I can do:
        raise MyCustomException(i) from e
        # what I actually want:
        # all_errors.append(MyCustomException(i) from e)
```

Is there a way to construct MyCustomException with all the initializations that `from e` does for me (setting `__cause__` or what ever else), but without throwing the it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no other way than to set `__cause__` manually.

But since you create a custom exception, this might be helpful:

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, cause=None)
        self.__cause__ = cause
```